# Win32Com in azureml

Tags: python

I want to work with .xlsm files is azure ml sdk. For that I want to use win32com.client which I have successfully used in my local python sdk. But when I tried to install win32com in azure ml studio it says:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Would anyone be able to advise me how to sort this issue? Is there any alternate packgae I can use to execute macros in xlsm file?

Many Thanks
Sruthy

Answer (score 0):

I think the version is new now and it can be installed via pip. Try this instead

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Please check the link as well
(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32)

Comment: When I tried to use pip install pypiwin32 the following error comes: "Collecting pypiwin32
  Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages."

Comment: Do you have a windows machine or something else. I Think its a platform issue. You need to upgrade pip as well `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` cuz it sometime happens due to pip. If not then its your platform issue because I have it on windows easily